# Post variable of Multi Select not working in php

Tags: php, html

**index.php**

```
<form method="post" action="next.php">
<select multiple size="10"  name="tpack" >

  <option value='1'>Gowtham</option>
     <option value='2'>Gowtham</option>
     <option value='3'>Gowtham</option>
     <option value='4'>Gowtham</option>
</select>
<input type="submit"> </form>
```

**next.php**

```
<?php foreach ($_POST['tpack'] as $names)
{
        print "You are selected $names<br/>";
} ?>
```

***I am getting error "Invalid argument supplied for foreach()"***

**when i tried next.php**

```
<?php print_r($_POST['tpack']); ?>
```

***I am not getting array.I am getting single max number of all four values in html.***

Comment: use `name="tpack[]"` :p

Comment: @HamZa, I got it now, yes.

Comment: @GowthamRajVungarala, you can close your question because the problem solved and this is a possible duplicate question.

Comment: i am new how to close this @SheikhHeera

Answer (score 4):

Ok looking at source code if you want the option to come through as an array you need to declare the form like this...  name="tpack[]" 
with square brackets to convert to an array

```
  <html>
  <body>
 <form method="post" action="post.php">
<select multiple size="10"  name="tpack[]" >

   <option value='1'>Gowtham</option>
   <option value='2'>Gowtham</option>
   <option value='3'>Gowtham</option>
   <option value='4'>Gowtham</option>
   </select>
 <input type="submit"> </form>
  </body>

</html>
```

hope this helps!!

Comment: This solution works, thanks it helped me